# How can Delphi records be initialized automatically?

Tags: delphi

To initialize Delphi records I've always added a method (class or object) that would initialize to known good defaults. Delphi also allows for defining record "constructors" with parameters, but you cannot define your own parameter-less "constructor".

```
TSomeRecord = record
 Value1: double;
 Value2: double;

 procedure Init;
end;

procedure TSomeRecord.Init;
begin
  Value1 := MaxDouble;
  Value2 := Pi;
end;
```

Given the record above there is no warning that a record has not been initialized. Developers may neglect to call `Init` on the record. Is there a way to **automatically** initialize records to my default, potentially more than just a simple `FillChar`;

For instance

```
var 
  LSomeRecord: TSomeRecord
begin
  // someone forgot to call LSomeRecord.Init here
  FunctionThatTakesDefaultSomeRecord(LSomeRecord);
end;
```

How can a record be initialized to my defaults automatically?

[Note]
I don't want to modify the problem after it has been answered. Any readers are directed to read the comments on best practices on using class methods for initialization instead of a mutating object method.

Comment: How about using a class instead or create a TSomeRecordFactory that returns initialized TSomeRecords. Or add a private variable you set in the init method.

Comment: Methods that mutate the state of value types (as your `Init` does) are evil. Use a static class function that returns a new value. And no you cannot auto-initialise a value type. Records are value types just like integers, floats etc.

Comment: I find it horrible that the Compiler cannot even warn you about passing uninitialized fields of records. But anyway - Is there a reason you're using `FillChar(..)`? So far, I have only seen `LSomeRecord := Default(TSomeRecord)`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why is mutating state a problem in this case since I cannot use the record threaded or non-threaded before initializing it?

Comment: In general it's a bad idea. Imagine passing such a record (a value type) to a function as a `const` parameter. You might hope that the value could not change, but a call to the method will change it. So, my rule is that methods on value types must never modify the state of the target instance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have a slightly less strict rule: publicly, records with methods are immutable. Private methods are however allowed to initialize or change state. But I also define constructors, something which you wouldn't do, IIRC.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Make sure that no public methods ever call private methods in that case....... Constructors are a bad idea for value types, in my view, because they make you think you need to destroy the instance. But I'm a `FreeAndNil`'er and so the compiler can't save me from that silliness. If you are a `Free`'er then the compiler can.  All the same, I like to use a static class function named `New` that makes it clear to the reader that a new value is being returned.

Comment: Some publc methods do call mutating prvate methods, but care is taken that they only modify the result before it is passed out or local intermediates. In other words, the interface is strictly immutable and does not inadvertently modify variables passed in.

Comment: Honestly, you are a `FreeAndNil`'er? Anyway, I think the name `Create` also indicates that a new value is, well, created.

Comment: @Rudy That makes no sense. If a public method can mutate state then const records can be modified. End of story. Create indicates a new value is recorded but one would normally want to pair that Create with a Free. So I prefer a different name.

Comment: No public method or operator will mutate state of the object itself, it only mutates state of result records that are still being constructed or of intermediate values. The intermediates are local and never leave the method. So the public interface is strictly that of an immutable type.

Comment: @David: example: in certain calculations in my BigInteger type, I need to increment or shift left intermediate values. Doing `a := a + 1;` would create a new instance each time. Incrementing one local BigInteger is much simpler and this value never leaves the method. So the public interface is strictly immutable, but the internals are not. Note that Java uses similar tricks (using the non-public MutableBigInteger internally and converting the final result to -- immutable -- BigInteger).

Comment: I never felt the need to automatically pair `Create` with `Free`. Think of situations like `myInterface := TMyImplementingClass.Create(params);`, where you would not call `Free` either.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: most public methods that return a record of the same type will have to modify the state of the result. If the modification is not very simple, it makes sense to use private mehods to perform that modification. As long as the public method does not modify `Self`, or its parameters, the public interface remains immutable.

Comment: @rudy my experience is that it is easier to recognise an interface because its type is prefixed with I.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't change the principle, does it?

Comment: @David: I didn't state anything incorrectly. I said: " I have a slightly less strict rule: **publicly, records with methods are immutable**. Private methods are however allowed to initialize or change state." That is indeed the case: **publicly, such records are immutable**. That means public methods do not (directly or indirectly) change the state of `Self` or of parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a hidden string field (which is automatically initialized to an empty string) to implement 'on time' initialization and implicit operators to hide implementation details. The code below shows how to implement a 'double' field which is automatically initialized to Pi.

```
program Project44;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TAutoDouble = record
  private
    FValue: double;
    FInitialized: string;
    procedure Initialize(const val: double = Pi);
  public
    class operator Implicit(const rec: TAutoDouble): double;
    class operator Implicit(const val: double): TAutoDouble;
  end;

  TSomeRecord = record
    Value1: TAutoDouble;
    Value2: TAutoDouble;
  end;

{ TAutoDouble }

procedure TAutoDouble.Initialize(const val: double);
begin
  if FInitialized = '' then begin
    FInitialized := '1';
    FValue := val;
  end;
end;

class operator TAutoDouble.Implicit(const rec: TAutoDouble): double;
begin
  rec.Initialize;
  Result := rec.FValue;
end;

class operator TAutoDouble.Implicit(const val: double): TAutoDouble;
begin
  Result.Initialize(val);
end;

var
  sr, sr1: TSomeRecord;

begin
  try
    Writeln(double(sr.Value1));
    Writeln(double(sr.Value2));
    sr.Value1 := 42;
    Writeln(double(sr.Value1));
    sr1 := sr;
    Writeln(double(sr.Value1));
    Writeln(double(sr.Value2));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

There's, however, no nice way to make this solution more generic regarding the default value -- if you need a different default value you have to clone TAutoDouble definition/implementation and change the default value.

Comment: This is one of those things that whilst you can do it, you should not

Comment: For the record, I agree with David.

Comment: I also agree, but it answers the question

Comment: FWIW there is no need to create TInterfacedObject, a handcrafted dummy VMT (see `System.Generics.Defaults` for example) or better using a string field that is set to anything than empty string should be enough.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Do you mean `FInitializer` could have been defined as a string? Also, what are you referring to with `System.Generics.Defaults` ?

Comment: The trick here is to add a field to the record that is initialized by the compiler/runtime (it does for any managed type just as IInterface or string) so you have a flag for the initialized state. The unit I mentioned uses handcrafted interface method tables to avoid the overhead of creating objects just to have an interface reference (`System.Rtti.pas` uses the same technique - look into `TValue.Create`). Allen Bauer used the same approach in his blog article about nullables (see http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/a-andquotnullableandquot-post-38869).

Comment: I agree with @StefanGlienke - it is better to use strings instead of interfaces in this case (but I keep forgetting that ...). I've updated the answer.

Comment: A wild thought: one could turn `FValue` into a `TArray<Double>`. This would be auto-initialized to `nil`, indicating an invalid value. If `FValue` is non-`nil` and its length is 1, `FValue[0]` is the valid "payload". It would probably be a little slower because of indirection. It would not require the string, though.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I've been down that road and it raises other problems. Such a record would be the same size as a pointer and thus being passed  via registers all the time causing potential problems with copies being initialized while the original is not. I once had such an issue and I had to add a dummy field to that record to make it bigger than size of pointer to prevent it being passed via register.

Comment: Why would copies be initialized when the original is not? Copies are just, well, copies.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: could you give or describe an example?

Comment: Change Primoz' code as you described and watch how `sr.Value1` and `sr.Value2` don't change after the first Writelns while they do with his approach.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: Will try.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: Depends on how you change it. My `Initialize()` is `SetLength(FValue, 1); FValue[0] := val;`. My `Implicit(): double` is `if FValue <> nil then Result := FValue[0] else Result := Pi;`.

Comment: @StefanGlienke: I would actually raise an exception if FValue is nil, but that is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 7):

Since Delphi 10.4, there are [Custom Managed Records](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Custom_Managed_Records)

```
  TMyRecord = record
    Value: Integer;
    class operator Initialize (out Dest: TMyRecord);
    class operator Finalize (var Dest: TMyRecord);
  end;
```

> The huge difference between this construction and what was previously available for records is the automatic invocation.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK you can't without resorting to tricks that aren't worth it (maybe using interface fields which are guaranteed to be initialized).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a nice feature ... but I guess you can use a factory of some kind? or just a humble method returning a record...

Comment: you need to post this as a comment not as an answer