# In Delphi, how to fix access violation on a FreeAndNil in 64-bit release build (when 64-bit debug build works)?

Tags: delphi, exception, 64-bit, access-violation

Here is some simplified code context to my question:

```
TSomeone = record
    FirstName: String;
    LastName: String;
    Picture: TGraphic;
end;

TSomeoneHelper = record helper for TSomeone
    public
        procedure Clear();
        procedure LoadFromFile(const Filename: String);
end;

procedure TSomeoneHelper.Clear();
begin
    Self.FirstName := '';
    Self.LastName:= '';

    try
        if Assigned(Self.Picture) then
            FreeAndNil(Self.Picture); // <---- Crash here in 64-bit release
    except
        Self.Picture := nil;
    end;
end;
```

Normally someone would declare a `TSomeone` variable and then call `myVar.LoadFromFile('myfile.blah')` to fill the record. In the `LoadFromFile` procedure a `TJPEGImage` (`TGraphic` descendant) is created and then assigned to `Picture`.

Since I'm not in a class (no constructor in `record helper`) I have no way to initialize `Picture` to `nil`. Because of that `FreeAndNil` crashes. What's weird is that on 32-bit builds, it seems initialized to `nil` but in 64 bit builds it's not (it's "Inaccessible value"). I added the `try except` for that reason. But even weirder in 64-bit release I get an access violation that is not catched by the `try except`.

To sum up:

- 32-bit release + debug builds are OK since `Picture` is initialized to `nil` because magic (?), so no exception - all is good
- 64-bit debug `Picture` is initialized "Inaccessible value" which trigger `Assigned` then `FreeAndNil` does an access violation but the `try` catches it so all is good
- 64-bit release (don't know how to debug CPU assembly so  not sure what happens) but the `try` don't catch the access violation and the error is thrown to the user so bad

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: An old suggested approach that not many were happy with was to use an extra field to track if the record has been initialized. See; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392920/how-can-delphi-records-be-initialized-automatically

Comment: `Assigned` will (almost) always fail for stack allocated records here.  It will return "true" even though the pointer is just dangling nonsense (because TGraphic is unmanaged and not initialized to `nil`). This has nothing to do with 32/64 bit - you're probably just getting lucky on the 32-bit build, or testing in a different way.  Adding a flag to the record won't help because that won't be guaranteed to be initialized either.  A record is going to make a messy implementation of this no matter what.  I'd prefer a class unless you have a massive reason to need record semantics here.

Comment: It would really help to see a [mcve].

Comment: As an alternative, you might consider something like base64 encoding your image file and assigning that to a `string` type if you really need record semantics.  This at least would force the image into a managed type that is guaranteed to be initialized to an empty string.  Using a `TBytes` dynamic array might be another option, depending on the image size.  Unmanaged reference types in records will always have these problems.

Comment: A `record` can have constructors, and even initializers in 10.4.  `TSomeone` should initialize itself before `Clear()` or `LoadFromFile()` is called on it.  For that matter, why use a `record helper` at all, and not put the methods in `TSomeone` directly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, but nothing forces the record's constructor to be called.  The consumer of the record would be required to remember to explicitly initialize the record, either by restricting themselves to constructing new instances using the constructor or by other initialization methods.  I think that's a bit clumsy.

Comment: @J that would be true prior to 10.4, but in 10.4 it can indeed be forced via the new ["Managed Records"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Custom_Managed_Records) feature. This is exactly the type of scenario that feature was invented for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I didn't know that, thanks!  Still, if you're stuck supporting older compilers that just makes things more complicated rather than less...

Comment: @J... indeed.  In which case, it would make sense to include a `Create()` constructor, or even a separate function, and just document that the user MUST call one of them when using `TSomeone` or else bad things can happen

Comment: @RemyLebeau True, but I think I'd rather just use a class instead, doubly so once these objects end up in structures like lists or dictionaries.  I think OP needs a strong reason to stick to record semantics.  I can't count the number of times I've started a design using records and then kicked myself later.  I don't think I've ever had a class where I've later thought "gee, I really wish this was a record instead".  Maybe that's just me...

Comment: I agree with @J. Using classes instead of record in this specific scenario would probably be much better choice. By using classes OP could design such class to have two constructors one without and another overloaded with ability to pass FileName as constructors parameter which would in turn allow loading of picture at class creation. So no need for additional cal to `LoadFromFile` method that OP now has in its Helper Class. Not to mention that there will no longer be need to call `Clear` that OP now also have in his helper class as that could be done inside destructor.

Comment: Also I don't see how OP could benefit of using records with his data structure since all of his record fields are references and thus data of those fields isn't stored in one continuous memory bloc lie it would be if those would be non-referenced data types which is when records offer some advantage over use of classes.

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that `if Assigned(X) then FreeAndNil(X)` reveals a misunderstanding. `X.Free` essentially does `if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy` and `FreeAndNil(X)` essentially does `X.Free; X := nil`. Hence, `if Assigned(X) then FreeAndNil(X)` is the same thing as `if Assigned(X) then if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy; X := nil` which has exactly the same effect as `FreeAndNil(X)` alone. But `Assigned` doesn't protect you from [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer), which you might get. **Local** variables of **non-managed types** are not initialized.

Comment: Also, @AlexV, you might not know that records can have functions and procedures (and members of varying visibility, like `strict private`, `private`, and `public`)? So you don't need a record helper at all here. You can simply do `TSomeone = record
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    Picture: TGraphic;
    procedure Clear;
    procedure LoadFromFile(const FileName: string);
end;`

Comment: It doesn't work in 64 bit debug build either. In fact it doesn't work anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it works differently between build type and architecture is just luck. This should not work anywhere (the OP comments just confirmed what I thought).

If using Delphi 10.4+ you use [Custom Managed Records](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Custom_Managed_Records) to initialize the (unmanaged) var to `nil` and the `Assigned()` call will not do access violations.

In the end I just refactored my code to use classes instead of records. In the constructor I initialize the var to `nil`. It's cleaner and work with *any* version of Delphi.

Comment: @J... Switched from records to classes and all is ok now. Everything makes more sense now!

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Did not know that records could have procedures/functions, I thought just helpers could. Nice to know! But for my case I switched to classes instead of records.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Just want to point out that members in a *class* always are initialized, so in this case you don't need to set `Picture` to `nil` in the class's constructor: by the time to constructor code is executed, the entire object has been overwritten with zeroes; in particular, this means that all integers are `0` and all pointers `nil`.